# ASP.NET Core on IIS just spinning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I have a React.NET frameworked app that lives in a ASP.NET Core that we're trying to place onto IIS. We have the base project responding to requests on the server, serving static resources, our react JS, our MVC routes, etc...

However, we are using AJAX GET requests to pull a JSON response from the backend MVC. When making this call, the server just sits and spins, no error or anything. There are no errors being logged either.

When we run the app on the same server via Visual Studio debug, everything works fine. (Same story for local.) Just seems we're missing something with IIS.

Here is the Startup.cs (some things are commented out per our testing but can see what we've attempted)

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddReact();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddLogging();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        /*if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }*/
        // Initialise ReactJS.NET. Must be before static files.
        /*app.UseReact(config =>
        {
            // If you want to use server-side rendering of React components,
            // add all the necessary JavaScript files here. This includes
            // your components as well as all of their dependencies.
            // See http://reactjs.net/ for more information. Example:
            //config
            //  .AddScript("~/Scripts/First.jsx")
            //  .AddScript("~/Scripts/Second.jsx");

            // If you use an external build too (for example, Babel, Webpack,
            // Browserify or Gulp), you can improve performance by disabling
            // ReactJS.NET's version of Babel and loading the pre-transpiled
            // scripts. Example:
            //config
            //  .SetLoadBabel(false)
            //  .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/Scripts/bundle.server.js");
        });*/


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Our Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            //.UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

aspsettings.json

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated. Been banging my head with this for the past few days.

Comment: Use a tool such as Fiddler to trace your AJAX calls first.

Comment: AJAX call is solid. It's working locally and I'm not seeing any interference from a firewall, etc... when on the server using postman.

Comment: trace the calls when the issue occurs. Running locally does not guarantee universally unless it is your day one to do web programming.